# Virtualmin Configuration

Tags: sendmail

I am trying to get Virtualmin setup and have reached a point where my noobish sysadmin skills aren't getting the job done. This is the message I get now when I try and refresh the configuration of Virtualmin.

BIND DNS server is installed, and the system is configured to use it. However, the default master DNS server XXXXXX is not a fully qualified domain name.

Sendmail is only accepting SMTP connections on the following ports : 127.0.0.1 port smtp. Email from other systems on the Internet will not be accepted. This can be changed in the Sendmail Mail Server module.

Please advise what I need to do to get Sendmail configured properly. Thanks!

Comment: **Questions involving web hosting control panels** are off-topic at [sf] because they [customize their systems beyond our ability to support](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/8055), and thus require support from the vendor or the web hosting industry. See [Where can I ask questions about web hosting control panels?](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/8094)

Answer (score 1):

I've created a [Virtualmin ServerTemplate](http://www.cloudartisan.com/2010/10/rightscale-servertemplate-virtualmin/) on RightScale.  You can use it to fire up a Virtualmin server on Amazon EC2.  If you want to play around with Virtualmin first without having to wrestle with its configuration, it might be just what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find the options for Sendmail by logging into Virtualmin, then choosing Webmin -> Servers -> Sendmail Mail Server.

There you will have your configuration options including which IPs the server should be listening on.

For more info one page you can check out is:
http://www.virtualmin.com/documentation/id,mail_relaying_with_virtualmin/

Answer (score 0):

The mail relaying module documentation that Doruk has mentioned is not at all relevant to this particular issue. You do not need that module for normal mail service, or to get rid of this error. You should not refer to that particular page at all for installation and initial configuration advice.

I don't have any servers with Sendmail handy, so I can't tell you specifically how to correct this sendmail error.

The name server error is super easy to fix, though: edit /etc/resolv.conf and add 127.0.0.1 as a nameserver.

I *am* wondering, however, why you've opted to install Virtualmin manually, if you're a newbie? It is incredibly challenging and time-consuming to setup a full-featured virtual hosting system (which is what Virtualmin manages). We provide an install script that does all of that configuration for you automatically on our download page at http://www.virtualmin.com/download

It sets up all of the components you need, and they will all Just Work when the installation has completed. You're currently nowhere close to getting a fully functional Virtualmin system, even after you've fixed these two little errors; you'll have a couple dozen other configuration changes to make even once these are fixed, and most of them are far more complex than these two.

I *strongly* suggest you not try to manually configure a virtual hosting system from scratch if you aren't an experienced system administrator. We have some documentation about a manual installation of Virtualmin, but it's not complete, and it expects a pretty high level of knowledge (because we expect non-technical users to use the install script we've provided).